# Como corregir el error de los botones utilizando Array en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, funciones, botón

Me ha surgido un problema en el cual yo le ingreso datos, en este caso *Nombres* por el input, y se me añaden a través del botón *Añadir*. Cuando yo le doy al botón *Cambio* para cambiar de posiciones a esos nombres, **tengo que volver a darle clic al botón *Añadir* para que se produzca el cambio de posiciones.**

```js
let users = [];

function pushData() {
    var inputText = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
    users.push(inputText);
    
    var pval = "";
    for(i=0; i<users.length; i++) {
        pval =pval + users[i]+"<ul></ul>";
    }
    
    document.getElementById('pText').innerHTML = pval;
}

function cambioNombres(array) {
    var j,x,i;

    for (i= array.length -1; i>0; i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random()*(i+1));
        x=array[i];
        array[i]=array[j];
        array[j]=x;
    }
}

cambioNombres(users);
```

```html
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="text" id="inputText"> 
        <button onclick="pushData()">Añadir</button>
        <button onclick="cambioNombres(users)">Cambio</button>

        <p id="pText"></p>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
    
</body>
```

No entiendo por que pasa eso y como debería arreglarlo para que solamente cuando le de al botón *Cambio* ahí se me realice el cambio de posiciones de nombres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cuando yo le doy al botón Cambio para cambiar de posiciones a esos nombres, tengo que volver a darle clic al botón Añadir para que se produzca el cambio de posiciones.

El problema es que en la función `cambioNombres()` cambias el orden del contenido del array `users`, pero este no se ve por pantalla por que nunca se hace un `innerHTML` o cualquier otra modificación al DOM.

La función `pushData()` realiza la modificación al DOM, y por eso mismo es que hasta presionar el botón que la llama se ven los cambios. Salo basta con modificar el DOM en  `cambioNombres()`.

```js
let users = [];

function pushData() {
    var inputText = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
    users.push(inputText);
    
    var pval = "";
    for(i=0; i<users.length; i++) {
        pval =pval + users[i]+"<ul></ul>";
    }
    
    document.getElementById('pText').innerHTML = pval;
}

function cambioNombres(array) {
    var j,x,i;

    for (i= array.length -1; i>0; i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random()*(i+1));
        x=array[i];
        array[i]=array[j];
        array[j]=x;
    }

    var pval = "";
    for(i=0; i<users.length; i++) {
        pval =pval + users[i]+"<ul></ul>";
    }

    document.getElementById('pText').innerHTML = pval;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="text" id="inputText"> 
        <button onclick="pushData()">Añadir</button>
        <button onclick="cambioNombres(users)">Cambio</button>

        <p id="pText"></p>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
    
</body>
```

Sin embargo, creo que es más apto definir otra función que se encarge de modificar el DOM con base al array `users`, esto haría el código más limpio.

```
const modificarDOM = (arr) => {
    var pval = "";
    for(i = 0;i < arr.length;i++) {
        pval = pval + `${arr[i]}<ul></ul>>`
    }

    document.getElementById('pText').innerHTML = pval;
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Excelente es lo que buscaba, seguiré practicando para mejorar! Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

El DOM interpreta un elemento que aun no esta listo al momento en que ejecutas `cambioNombres(users)` en ese momento aun no se reconoce el eleme to users ya que fue cargado antes de que declararas `let users = []`

Para ello, debes modificar tu función para no recibir el parámetro `array` y vas actualizando con la variable global `users`

```
function cambioNombres() {
    let array = users;
    var j,x,i;
    ....
}
```